# How to Update a Dependency in a Julia Package Under Development

Tags: package, julia

I am developing a Julia package that I have added via `dev <github url>`. I can enter Pkg mode in the terminal via `] activate` and get the prompt I want.

Suppose I want to change the version of Flux used with the package from v0.9.0 to v0.10.0. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pkg> update Flux` or `pkg> add Flux@0.10` in the same environment where you have added the package you are developing.

Comment: Running `resolve` after `add` may be required as well.